# How to make sure that a Symfony form does not contain unnecessary elements?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am a beginner in Symfony, so this question might be simple for those who are more experienced in this framework.

I am building forms and I have several possible types of items in forms. At this moment these are:

- text
- html
- image

However, in the future there will be many more items. Previously, the project generated all items into their place (text, html and image) and hidden those which are not needed for the specific form item (maximum one is needed). However, I intend to avoid adding items I do not need. Since I do not know at the point `buildForm` of an arbitrary item is running whether it is text, html or image, so at this point all of them are added (I know this is counter-intuitive, but this is a code I try to refactor):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('layoutTypeInput', TextType::class);

    $builder->add('blockTypeOutput', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'MyPageBundle:BlockTypeOutput',
        'choice_label' => 'titleHu',
        'required' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Válassz blokk kimenetet!',
        'empty_data' => null,
    ));

    $builder->add('text', TextType::class, $this->getBlockTypeOptions('text'));

    $builder->add('html', TextareaType::class, $this->getBlockTypeOptions('html'));

    $builder->add('image', ImageSelectType::class, $this->getBlockTypeOptions('image'));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPostSetData'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
}
```

Now, I have a function which removes the unnecessary elements of a `form`:

```
private function removeUnnecessaryItems(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, $key)
{
    $keys = ['text', 'html', 'image'];
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        if ($key !== $k) $form->remove($k);
    }
}
```

And inside `onPostSetData` I call it like this:

```
    $this->removeUnnecessaryItems($form, $inputObject->getLayoutTypeIdText());
```

and finally, in the twig I determine what should be generated into the form:

```
            {% for ioLayoutBlock in form.ioLayoutBlocks %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                        {{ form_errors(ioLayoutBlock.layoutTypeInput) }}
                        {{ioLayoutBlock.layoutTypeInput.vars.label}}
                    </div>
                    {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.layoutTypeInput, {'attr' : {'class':'hidden'}}) }}
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
                        {{ form_errors(ioLayoutBlock.blockTypeOutput) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.blockTypeOutput, {'attr' : {'class':'blockTypeOutput'}}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        {% if ioLayoutBlock.text is defined %}
                            {{ form_errors(ioLayoutBlock.text) }}
                            {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.text, {'attr':{'class':'hidden uniqueInput ioLayoutBlock_text' }}) }}
                        {% elseif ioLayoutBlock.html is defined %}
                            {{ form_errors(ioLayoutBlock.html) }}
                            {% if layout.layoutType.name == 'userHTML' %}
                                <div class="input-group ioLayoutBlock_html hidden">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon myAdminForm" target="_blank" data-my-href="page/{{ page.id }}/wysiwyg/{{ layout.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                                    {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.html, {'attr':{'class':'uniqueInput wysiwyg' }}) }}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.html, {'attr':{'class':'hidden uniqueInput wysiwyg ioLayoutBlock_html' }}) }}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% elseif ioLayoutBlock.image is defined %}
                            {{ form_errors(ioLayoutBlock.image) }}
                            {{ form_widget(ioLayoutBlock.image, {'attr':{'class':'hidden uniqueInput ioLayoutBlock_image' }}) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

and if I load the page, everything is shown correctly, but unfortunately, when I try to submit the `form`, it gives the error of

> This form should not contain extra fields.

as many times as many `form` items I have. If I comment out the call on `removeUnnecessaryItems` inside `onPostSetData` and subsequently remove the conditionals from the twig, like:

```
{% if ioLayoutBlock.text is defined %}
```

then everything works, but that's how it worked before the refactor. Ideally I would like to avoid adding so many unnecessary things at `buildForm`, but I do not know how can I load up any meaningful data there to determine the type of the item. Alternatively I would like to ensure that the items are successfully removed at the events where I do know their type, without the form errors on submit I described above. So, my question is: How can I avoid generating all kinds of unnecessary stuff into my form without being blocked by submit errors?

Comment: Is there a domain rule that require you to remove items of the form after the form has been created? Or it jsut the way it has been done?

Comment: @goto I think it is the way it has been done, but I am new both to the project and to Symfony, so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to give a parameter to your form

```
$form = $this->createForm(DynamicType::class, $user, [
    'layout_type_id' => $layoutTypeIdText,
]),
```

Then adds the fields depending of the param

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->layout_type = $options['LayoutTypeId'];
    // [...]
    if ($this->layout_type !== 'text' )
        $builder->add('text', TextType::class, $this->getBlockTypeOptions('text'));
        // [...]
    ;
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        // [...]
        'layout_type_id' => null,
    ]);
}
```

With this approch, the good part is you don't to duplicate your logic in twig, the form get the fields it needs, so you can just render the form using

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

For your specific case you need to avoid adding the items at buildForm, to handle the default empty values at onPreSubmit (as the transformers will not be called if the items are not added at buildForm) and to add the effective items at onPreSubmit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your idea, but I am so noob in Symfony that it might take a while while I try this out, including, but not limited to the needed time to find where the form is being created (not by calling a createForm). I am in general much quicker, but with Smyfony I kindly ask you for some patience before I can give you any feedback.

Comment: @LajosArpad No problem, Just ping me if needed

Comment: Your idea was good, but was not an option in my specific case. I needed to avoid adding the items at buildForm, to handle the default empty values at onPreSubmit (as the transformers will not be called if the items are not added at buildForm) and to add the effective items at onPreSubmit. Note that things were not duplicated at my twig, as I needed to display the values differently in the cases of text, html and image form items. I upvote your answer and if you edit it and add the information I gave here, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct using form listeners, they are the way to go for your use case.
I see 2 sub scenarii:

- the form data is coming from the Model, you fill it inside the controller
- a new item is added to the form, client-side (via the prototype).

I'm getting from your example code that users can't add new items dynamically. If you want to do so, the code is just slightly different.

Remains the first scenario. The trick is not to remove, but to add forms inside the `PRE_SET_DATA` listener:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('layoutTypeInput', TextType::class);

    $builder->add('blockTypeOutput', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'MyPageBundle:BlockTypeOutput',
        'choice_label' => 'titleHu',
        'required' => false,
        'placeholder' => 'Válassz blokk kimenetet!',
        'empty_data' => null,
    ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents:: PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    // ...
}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData(); // This contains model data (ie., from controller)
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $type = 'image'; // Read type from your model

    $formType = $this->getFormTypeForType($type);

    $builder->add($type, formType, $this->getBlockTypeOptions($type));
}

private function getFormTypeForType($type)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'image':
            return ImageSelectType::class;
        // ...
        default:
            // Up to you, you can decide on setting a default type or enforcing that the type is correct
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unsupported type');
    }
}
```

With that code, you can keep the same Twig.

I'm not sure on what you are trying to do with `layoutTypeInput` and `blockTypeOutput`. Maybe we are answering just partially here, don't hesitate on posting the full use case.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but since the other answer was given earlier and edited to reflect my situation, I had to accept it. But your solution is just as good.